# php - download large file from ftp server and limiting download speed

Tags: php, file, download, ftp, zip

i have website for storing large zip file and upload it to ftp server in php
now i want to **download the file from ftp and limiting download speed

and be able to resuming and pause download** i have this code :

```
    $file_path = 'ftp://'.$ftp_username.':'.$ftp_password.'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$ftp_filename_withDiR ;
$filesize_ftp =  filesize($file_path);
ob_clean();
$download_rate = $Mbspeed;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header("Content-Length:".$filesize_ftp);
  header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$filenamea);
  flush();
  $file = fopen($file_path, "r");
  while(!feof($file)) {echo fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));flush();usleep(200);      }
```

But i can't pause the download ! any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. Pausing the download is up to the clilent-side, PHP has nothing to do with it. That's either going to be handled by your browser, or Javascript. 2. Resuming a download [again, from the server-side] requires you to look for a [`Range:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header in the HTTP request which should tell you where in the file to resume reading bytes. This will probably show up as `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']`.

Comment: yes thank you , but when i use it i can't downloading large files only mini files and i do not know the reason :(

Comment: Then post the code that's not working and ask why, you'll probably get an actual answer.

Comment: *"But i can't pause the download"* - What's sooo vague! How exactly are you trying to pause the download?

Comment: im using idm to download files .

Comment: i try to use this code **https://gist.github.com/fzerorubigd/3899077** and work good for local files but the download stops when i try to download files from ftp